# R or MATLAB - Matching column name to modify the corresponding cell in a matrix

Tags: r, matlab, matrix, matching

I would like to convert the column with NODE as header in a Matrix below to their corresponding Gene as follows:

```
   NODE Gene1 Gene2 Gene3 Gene4 Gene5 NODE1 NODE2 NODE3
1 NODE1  0.98  0.98    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
2 NODE2    NA    NA   0.8   0.8    NA    NA    NA    NA
3 NODE3    NA    NA    NA    NA  0.72  0.72    NA    NA
4 NODE4    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   0.6   0.6
```

As

```
NODE1 = Gene1 and Gene2
NODE2 = Gene3 and Gene4
NODE3 = Gene5 and NODE1 = Gene5 and Gene 1 and Gene2
```

I would like to move cells in NODE1 NODE2 and NODE3 columns to their corresponding Gene colunms to output a file like this:

```
   NODE Gene1 Gene2 Gene3 Gene4 Gene5 
1 NODE1  0.98  0.98    NA    NA    NA    
2 NODE2    NA    NA   0.8   0.8    NA    
3 NODE3  0.72  0.72    NA    NA  0.72    
4 NODE4  0.6   0.6     NA   0.6  0.6
```

Are there any methods of doing this?  Can I use R or MATLAB to do this?

Best regards,

Catherine

Comment: I can't say I fully understand your desired output. What does `NODE4` correspond to?

Comment: Node4 stands for Node2 and Node3.  So they represent the corresponding genes in node2 and node3 too.  could you mind to give me some guidance how to do it with R?

Answer (score 1):

In Matlab you can do it like this:

```
    clear all
    nrgenes=5;
    nrnodes=4;
    matrix=zeros(nrnodes,nrgenes+nrnodes);
    matrix(1,1:2)=0.98;
    matrix(2,3:4)=0.8;
    matrix(3,5:6)=0.72;
    matrix(4,7:8)=0.6;

    for i=1:nrnodes
        for j=nrgenes+1:nrgenes+nrnodes
            if (matrix(i,j)~=0)
                matrix(i,1:nrgenes)=matrix(i,1:nrgenes)+matrix(i,j)*logical(matrix(j-nrgenes,1:nrgenes));
            end
        end
    end
    result=matrix(1:nrnodes,1:nrgenes);
```

Some caveats:

- You maybe have to run this twice to expand all the entries depending on the configuration of entries, but I think you get the idea how to do this from the code.
- there's a slight error in the Node4 line of your example result.
- This is coded with two nested for loops. Slow and inefficient for large matrices, but easier to understand. You maybe have to vectorize for large matrices to improve execution time.